# Pass int to webapi

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I know this has been asked a thousand times. But I can't find my error. I narrowed it down by testing it without a parameter, which worked and then tried various things. Like, get or post, [FromBody] or not. etc.
Perhaps I should just show my code or I should stop for today and just celebrate that it is almost weekend.

```
[HttpGet] // also tried post instead of get
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); // breakpoint set, not hit
}
```

My Js code:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj["id"] = parseInt(id);

var json = JSON.stringify(myObj);
alert(json);  // display: { id = 2134 }, seems fine to me

$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // also tried post
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/api/CheckPossible/Get',
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('failure');
    }
});
```

I have received a lot of bad requests (400) and I did got it to work without a parameter. So it is not a routing issue.

**edit**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/api/CheckPossible/Get/?id=1234', // also tried Get?id=1234
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('failure');
    }
});
```

Did not work. Perhaps I am missing something else too

Comment: For get request you need to pass the parameter as part of the url, you don't need to send it differently. Chaning url on JavaScript to `/api/CheckPossible/Get/123` should work. Replace `123` whatever dynamic value you ar3 getting from parseInt(id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a http message body to a `GET` method, you have to pass parameters either in the URL or in the header. For a web api you should pass them in the URL and you can do this as a query string or as part of the URL.

To get it to work with the query string change the url to

```
url: '/api/CheckPossible/?id=' + myObj["id"],
```

leave out the `data` as this won't do anything with `get`.

If you want to make the parameter a part of the URL then change your route to include it. I prefer the Route attribute for flexible routing, you can also change the global routing scheme.

```
[HttpGet] // also tried post instead of get
[Route("api/CheckPossible/{id:int}"]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
}
```

and change your url to

```
url: '/api/CheckPossible/' + myObj["id"]
```

Comment: And what if I do not want the querystring? Only option is to post and then use frombody?

Comment: @JPHellemons - it *is* a routing issue. Remove the `get` from your url as you are probably not inluding it in your global routing scheme.

Comment: It works, somehow my breakpoint was not set anymore, lol. `url: '/api/CheckPossible/Get/?id=' + myObj["id"],` can accept answer over 2 minutes.

Comment: Glad you helped out ;) and thanks for updating your answer.