# Dot net core API failing with Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int64'

Tags: api, .net-core

I am calling a .Net Core 3.1 Web API and getting the error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int64'.

```
    RequestPath: /fulfillment/api/v1/orderitems/12579618/isuseinreport/true/orderitementities
    SpanId: |4b43f9c5-4a4b193f28fac198.
    TraceId: 4b43f9c5-4a4b193f28fac198
    ParentId: 

Connection ID "17149707382637556404", Request ID "800172b6-0000-ee00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int64'.
   at HistOrderAPI.Controllers.OrderItemEntitiesController.ListOrderItemEntitiesByOrderItemID(Int64 InOID, Nullable`1 InIsUseInReport)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

The value being converted in the URL is **12579618** and should not be a problem for Int64.

Comment: There is a difference between converting `"12579618"` to `12579618` and casting a string to an int.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: You haven't provided the signature of your method `/orderitems/{id:int}/isuseinreport/{isinuse:bool}`?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47349988/437393